# generating the value of a 10 order polynomial and its derivative in C

Tags: c, polynomial-math

Am trying to generate the value of a 10 order polynomial with 11 coefficients. Am also trying to generate its derivative. i have written a three functions shown below.
this code  generates the value of the polynomial.a1 upto a10 are the coefficients.

```
float polynm( float a0,float a1,float a2,float a3,float a4,float a5,float a6,float a7,float a8,float a9,float a10,float x)
     {
          float poly = a0 + a1*x + a2*pow(x,2)+a3*pow(x,3)+a4*pow(x,4)+a5*pow(x,5)+a6*pow(x,6)+a7*pow(x,7)+a8*pow(x,8)+a9*pow(x,9)+a10*pow(x,10);
             return poly;
             }
```

this code generates the value of the derivative of the polynomial it calls a function deri

```
 float polynm_der(float a0,float a1,float a2,float a3,float a4,float a5,float a6,float a7,float a8,float a9,float a10,float x)
    {  float der = a1 + a2*deri(x,2)+a3*deri(x,3)+a4*deri(x,4)+a5*deri(x,5)+a6*deri(x,6)+a7*deri(x,7)+a8*deri(x,8)+a9*deri(x,9)+a10*deri(x,10);
       return der;
       }
deri is below
float deri(float x,int n)
   {   
         float term_der = n*pow(x,n-1);
           return term_der;
           }
```

the code for the polynomial is inefficient.if i wanted to generate an 100 order polynomial it would become impossible.  is there  a way i can generate the polynomial and its derivative maybe recursively to avoid the unwieldy code.

Comment: I like the way you use 10 parameters, but slight abbreviation of function names

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to accept an array of coefficients and its length:

```
float poly(int x, float coefficients[], int order)
{
    int idx;
    float total;

    for (idx = 0; idx < order; idx++)
        total += coefficients[idx] * pow(x, idx);
    return total;
}
```

The recursive solution would be beautiful, but this isn't Lisp. Anyway, a similar approach can be used for derivatives. Just keep in mind the fact that in C, array parameters to functions turn into pointers, so you can't use cool things like `sizeof` to get their lengths.

**Edit:** In response to the comment, you can enforce your requirements when the `coefficients` array is constructed. Alternatively, if you're not in charge of that code, you can stick it in the function (hackishly) like so:

```
if (coefficients[0] == 0 || coefficients[1] == 0 || coefficients[order-1] == 0)
    assert(0);
```

Comment: +1. BTW it is better to use [Horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) or at least use `pow(x,n) == pow(x,n-1)*x` within the `for` loop.

Comment: the first,second and last coefficients cannot be 0. how do i enforce that in an array so that a user is not allowed to enter 0.

Comment: Ouch. Don't use pow, and use Horner rule. You are exposing yourself to catastrophic cancellation for most typical 10 degree polynomials that you find in the wild (eg. interpolation polynomials).

Comment: Wow, it's been a long time since I've seen Horner (or synthetic division) mentioned; completely forgot about it. I'm not going to edit the question to use it though, since that feels dishonest. The code above is a literal translation of the question. If someone wants to write a better answer, I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: the user would be entering the a values of the coefficients and i would read them with a for loop. my users dont know anything about c. so i would like to give them a warning message when they attempt to enter 0 and prompt them to enter another value. how would i do that

Comment: @Wasswa: Check the values in the loop. If the index is in your set of required nonzero indices, verify that it's nonzero. If it isn't, print your warning message and have them try again.

Comment: i have a problem with the function above when i try to call it.like this ynew = y - (poly(y,*coefficients,11)/poly_der(y,*coefficients,11)); i get an error when compiling which says conflicting types for 'poly' and previous implicit declaration of 'poly' was here. It takes me back to the expression above when i click the error.What could be the cause of the error.it does the same for poly_der which is similar to poly but calculates the derivative of the polynomial.

Comment: Two things: First, don't dereference coefficients, so call it as `poly(x, coefficients, order)`. Second, make sure you put your function definition before where it's called in the source file. Either that, or include a prototype. If you already have a prototype, make sure it matches the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the functions to take the x value, an array of coefficients, and then the length.